# JPA when entity bean @Id property get populated with value

Tags: jpa

It would be really helpful if someone can explain me when property annotated with @Id get populated with some value for an entity bean.

I was trying with "Table" generation type and while debugging found that property get populated when entity manager called persist method.

But I have also seen examples where sequences are used and @Id property get populated the time we create entity bean object.

So is it specific to the approach we are taking for primary key generation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what generation strategy you choose the value for @Id field is determined when the entity is being saved (persisted to the DB) for the first time.

If you try to save an entity with @Id field being already set - this will lead to an update attempt.